# Electrical arc transmission in welding

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, lightning

Can anyone explain the physics behind this picture?  To give you a little background it is a photo from insta gram no copyright infringement intended here. The photo is a welding tig torch there is a a high frequency arc start that allows electrical connection to be established. This photo depicts that first moment when the arc is being established such that welding can begin. I’m interested in the points being connected to the metal plate and the pattern and the symmetry involved here. My question is what determines the amount of contact points being established? What determines the pattern for the connection? Also the spacing between the points and the parrallel behavior with the current being observed? The electrode is Tungsten. The metal here is carbon steel. The current is usually reverse dc polarity. What keeps the connection points separated and the electric current in parrallel and why not a more direct straight path to the steel. I realize I’m asking a lot of questions I’m hoping for a generalized response that may shed light on some of my questions above.
[image]

Comment: Adding comments from https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/305277/user34314: "I wonder about the exposure settings. This is an awfully well lit photo, so I wonder if it was longer exposure to get the background or something like that and you may actually be seeing the high frequency. Instead of multiple parallel arcs, I wonder if each parallel set is actually a single arc path moving out (like a jacob's ladder moves up) and the frequency is being picked up by the camera?"

Comment: "I have no basis for that guess other than the fact that I can't look at an arc through any welding goggles and see the arc that well without everything around it going completely black, so it makes it seem that the photo has something special going on with it. It could just be a bright flash pointed at the background, I suppose."